# Problem with blas and lapack in makefile

Tags: compiling, make, fortran

I am running and dual boot with a USB of the latest Ubuntu version. I am trying to run code and compile a make file and need lapack and blas to compile it. I am having trouble getting the code to find the location of blas and lapack:

[image: makefile in screenshot]

When I search for blas and lapack with `whereis` I get this:

[image: files in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu]

I tried these directories in the code and get the same error

When I try compiling my make file I get this:

[image: no rule to make target numeric.mod]

I need help calling lapack and blas to compile the make file and get it to run.

I even tried moving blas and lapack folders on to the desktop and using those locations and no luck.

What else can I try?

Comment: Please don't post terminal text as images.

Comment: I'm not sure that `-L` supports multiple `:`-separated paths in a single option, does it? try separating them like `-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas`. Better yet, make use of `pkg-config`.

Comment: I still get the same error

Comment: Why do you believe the make error "no rule to make target 'numeric.mod'" is related to the linking of blas and/or lapack?

Comment: Im pretty sure it’s because when I compile the make file it works till then and that part is where lapack and blas are used

Answer (score 0):

You have to install both libraries with their headers from the repository

```
sudo apt-get install libopenblas-dev liblapack-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Some "code" (are we talking R here ?) requires the -dev header packages if code is to be compiled (but please always put packages and error msgs in to get a qualified response.

If you're sure you've got the right packages installed (don't ever move the folders they're located in unless you really know what you're doing) you can try the following:

You can find out if you have the -dev headers already by doing

```
sudo apt search <pkgname> (eg liblapack ?) 
# try also something like:
sudo apt search liblapack-dev
# if dev packages are missing:
sudo apt install liblapack-dev
```

Hope that helps

Comment: just a note - APT commands that only query the database like `search` `show` `policy` don't require `sudo`